# Install Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, lubuntu, 17.04

I have Lubuntu 17.04 and I want to downgrade to Lubuntu 16.04 to access an application that is not yet compatible with 17.04. I am getting an error message when trying to open the install file:

```
'Could not open "mt86plus"
archive type not supported'
```

Any ideas? I am very unfamiliar with Linux so I need very detailed instructions. Thanks in advance.

[image: error image]

Comment: You don't downgrade. If you need 16.04 install new. But perhaps there are better ways, like finding out if there are alternatives for the application you need. A different question specifically about that application and Ubuntu 17.04 is what I suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Why you opened up the `iso` file with the archieve manager in the first place? Search for a tutorial on how to write it on a flash drive and then boot up from it, select `Try Lubuntu` and when you see the desktop click the `Install Lubuntu` icon. Follow the instactions and answear the prompts like a good person! Good Luck!